# javascript unresponsive in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, explorer

I wonder whether someone could please help me with this problem. I have created a test webpage which includes javascript. I have had the code checked to make sure it should work (clicking on an image reduces the transparency of a movie to half), and the good people of stack overflow have verified it works. However, when I test the page by loading it from my desktop either in chrome or IE the code is unresponsive. The picture and video load fine and have the correct id for the code to run, but just aren't working :(

- I have checked chrome and IE settings to make sure javascript is enabled.

What could be going wrong?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#picture_on").click(function () {
        $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
            opacity: '0.5'
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried `opacity : 0.5` (i.e., without the single quotes)? Just a hunch...

Comment: Your reference to jquery and your own script need to be in separate <script> elements.

Comment: +1 on both comments above. 1) Remove the single quotes, 2) Reference jquery and your on script in two separate <script> tags

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try it now and will get back to you ASAP :)

Comment: Still not working chaps. Removed the single quotes and added an extra set of script tags, still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone. This has been driving me mad.

ne1410s was right. I didn't use seperate script tags. So I changed it and was bamboozled as I had nested the script tags instead of closing off the Jquery tag.

Glad that is solved though... final working code looks like this...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#picture_on").click(function () {
        $("#MinecraftVideo").animate({
            opacity: '0.5'
        });
    });
});

</script>
```